# Check Constant in a FOR statement

Tags: ios, for-loop, constants

I have values stored in a `constant.h class`. How would I reference these if a foreach statement?

```
#define bLevel 2
#define aLevel 2
#define cLevel 3
#define tLevel 4
```

I know how to iterate over a NSArray but I'm not sure how I would achieve it with Constants

```
NSArray *text = @[@"text1", @"text2", @"text3", @"text4", @"text5", @"text6"];

    for (NSString *check in text) {

//Continue for statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an array, you need to store the constants as objects.

```
#define bLevel @2
#define aLevel @2
```

Then you can do

```
for (NSNumber *n in @[bLevel, aLevel]) {
   int i = n.intValue;
   // etc.
}
```

OR

```
#define bLevel 2
#define aLevel 2
```

and

```
for (NSNumber *n in @[@(bLevel), @(aLevel)]) { 
// ...
```

Comment: Instead of changing how `bLevel` and the others are defined, change how you create the array: `@[ @(bLevel), @(aLevel) ]`.